# Absolute Position Error in IE8 with Doctype Declared

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have looked through a number of questions similar to mine but without discovering a solution yet. I have an image with class `.header-promo` which is being positioned through the following CSS:

```
#header .header-promo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 82px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

I am using the `HTML5 doctype`, but the image is still being positioned completely wrong (at top left) in `IE8`. Any suggestions would be most appreciated. Thank you, and if you care to view the live site, you may do so at http://www.mainstreetveterinary.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting the element it looks like IE8 is not picking up the style for that element because it is in a media query. IE8 does not support media queries, but here is a plugin that you could try: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond